# Open image in new dedicated page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone help me with a script that will open up a click image in a new page, **not a new window**?

I have a single dedicated HTML page that will be used for various images to be opened up in when the image link is clicked.

Any idea's or direction would be greatly appreciated, you guys are the Best!

Sorry about that. I'll try to explain it better.
I have an html page called "Detailed Photo". I would like any image on my entire website when clicked to open up in this web page called "Detailed Photo".

Sorry to ask this, but could the person that just posted an answer regarding it being a vanilla .js please re-post that answer. My browser closed that window and I lost that answer.... It is what I needed.

OK GUYS,,,, You did GREAT!!! You gave me the tools to get done what I needed and it worked fantastic...

THANK YOU! all for your help. I only hope the best for all of you,,,, and yes, God is Good!!

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: not clear what expectations are. Can wrap image in a link with same  href and it will display just as image. If you want html though you need a better explanation

Comment: if you have a web server that can generate html dynamically you can pass the image ID (a URL or whatever) as a query string parameter to the URL that generates your Detailed Photo page.

Comment: Keep in mind that you sometimes don't have control over the `target` attribute.  It is sometimes set as a preference in the borwser to have a default `target` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Just make it a link

```
<a href=IMG.jpg ><IMG src=IMG.JPG></a>
```

When you click the full image only will appear

Answer (score -1):

Maybe:

```
$('body').html('<img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/T6tUh68f6E0/maxresdefault.jpg" style="width:100%;height:auto"></img>');
```